# Fill matrix of occurences from column/row arrays of indexes

Tags: python, arrays, numpy, matrix, indexing

I'm searching for an efficient way to create a matrix of occurrences from two arrays that contains indexes, one represents the **row indexes** in this matrix, the other, the column ones.

eg. I have:

```
#matrix will be size 4x3 in this example
#array of rows idxs, with values from 0 to 3
[0, 1, 1, 2, 2, 2, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3]
#array of columns idxs, with values from 0 to 2
[0, 1, 1, 1, 2, 2, 0, 1, 2, 0, 2, 2, 2, 2]
```

And need to create a matrix of occurrences like:

```
[[1  0  0]
 [0  2  0]
 [0  1  2]
 [2  1  5]]
```

I can create an array of one hot vectors in a simple form, but cant get it work when there is more than one occurrence:

```
n_rows    = 4
n_columns = 3
#data
rows    = np.array([0, 1, 1, 2, 2, 2, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3])
columns = np.array([0, 1, 1, 1, 2, 2, 0, 1, 2, 0, 2, 2, 2, 2])
#empty matrix
new_matrix = np.zeros([n_rows, n_columns])
#adding 1 for each [row, column] occurrence:
new_matrix[rows, columns] += 1
print(new_matrix)
```

Which returns:

```
[[ 1.  0.  0.]
 [ 0.  1.  0.]
 [ 0.  1.  1.]
 [ 1.  1.  1.]]
```

It seems like indexing and adding a value like this doesn't work when there is more than one occurrence/index, besides printing it seems to work just fine:

```
print(new_matrix[rows, :])
```

:

```
[[ 1.  0.  0.]
 [ 0.  1.  0.]
 [ 0.  1.  0.]
 [ 0.  1.  1.]
 [ 0.  1.  1.]
 [ 0.  1.  1.]
 [ 1.  1.  1.]
 [ 1.  1.  1.]
 [ 1.  1.  1.]
 [ 1.  1.  1.]
 [ 1.  1.  1.]
 [ 1.  1.  1.]
 [ 1.  1.  1.]
 [ 1.  1.  1.]]
```

So maybe I'm missing something there? Or this cant be done and I need to search for another way to do it?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use `np.add.at`, specifying a tuple of indices:

```
>>> np.add.at(new_matrix, (rows, columns), 1)
>>> new_matrix
array([[ 1.,  0.,  0.],
       [ 0.,  2.,  0.],
       [ 0.,  1.,  2.],
       [ 2.,  1.,  5.]])
```

`np.add.at` operates on the array [in-place](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/In-place_algorithm), adding `1` as many times to the indices as specified by the `(row, columns)` tuple.

Comment: Beautiful! Thank you!

Answer (score 2):

**Approach #1**

We can convert those pairs to linear indices and then use [`np.bincount`](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy-1.13.0/reference/generated/numpy.bincount.html) -

```
def bincount_app(rows, columns, n_rows, n_columns):
    # Get linear index equivalent
    lidx = (columns.max()+1)*rows + columns

    # Use binned count on the linear indices
    return np.bincount(lidx, minlength=n_rows*n_columns).reshape(n_rows,n_columns)
```

Sample run -

```
In [242]: n_rows    = 4
     ...: n_columns = 3
     ...: 
     ...: rows    = np.array([0, 1, 1, 2, 2, 2, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3])
     ...: columns = np.array([0, 1, 1, 1, 2, 2, 0, 1, 2, 0, 2, 2, 2, 2])

In [243]: bincount_app(rows, columns, n_rows, n_columns)
Out[243]: 
array([[1, 0, 0],
       [0, 2, 0],
       [0, 1, 2],
       [2, 1, 5]])
```

**Approach #2**

Alternatively, we can sort the linear indices and get the counts using `slicing` to have our second approach, like so -

```
def mask_diff_app(rows, columns, n_rows, n_columns):
    lidx = (columns.max()+1)*rows + columns
    lidx.sort()
    mask = np.concatenate(([True],lidx[1:] != lidx[:-1],[True]))
    count = np.diff(np.flatnonzero(mask))
    new_matrix = np.zeros([n_rows, n_columns],dtype=int)
    new_matrix.flat[lidx[mask[:-1]]] = count
    return new_matrix
```

**Approach #3**

This seems like a straight-forward one with sparse matrix [`csr_matrix`](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy/reference/generated/scipy.sparse.csr_matrix.html) as well, as it does accumulation on its own for repeated indices. The benefit is the memory efficiency, given that it's a sparse matrix, which would be noticeable if you are filling a small number of places in the output and a sparse matrix output is okay.

The implementation would look something like this -

```
from scipy.sparse import csr_matrix

def sparse_matrix_app(rows, columns, n_rows, n_columns):
    out_shp = (n_rows, n_columns)
    data = np.ones(len(rows),dtype=int)
    return csr_matrix((data, (rows, columns)), shape=out_shp)
```

If you need a regular/dense array, simply do -

```
sparse_matrix_app(rows, columns, n_rows, n_columns).toarray()
```

Sample output -

```
In [319]: sparse_matrix_app(rows, columns, n_rows, n_columns).toarray()
Out[319]: 
array([[1, 0, 0],
       [0, 2, 0],
       [0, 1, 2],
       [2, 1, 5]])
```

---

#### Benchmarking

Other approach(es) -

```
# @cᴏʟᴅsᴘᴇᴇᴅ's soln
def add_at_app(rows, columns, n_rows, n_columns):
    new_matrix = np.zeros([n_rows, n_columns],dtype=int)
    np.add.at(new_matrix, (rows, columns), 1)
```

**Timings**

Case #1 : Output array of shape `(1000, 1000)` and no. of indices = `10k`

```
In [307]: # Setup
     ...: n_rows = 1000
     ...: n_columns = 1000
     ...: rows = np.random.randint(0,1000,(10000))
     ...: columns = np.random.randint(0,1000,(10000))

In [308]: %timeit add_at_app(rows, columns, n_rows, n_columns)
     ...: %timeit bincount_app(rows, columns, n_rows, n_columns)
     ...: %timeit mask_diff_app(rows, columns, n_rows, n_columns)
     ...: %timeit sparse_matrix_app(rows, columns, n_rows, n_columns)
1000 loops, best of 3: 1.05 ms per loop
1000 loops, best of 3: 424 µs per loop
1000 loops, best of 3: 1.05 ms per loop
1000 loops, best of 3: 1.41 ms per loop
```

Case #2 : Output array of shape `(1000, 1000)` and no. of indices = `100k`

```
In [309]: # Setup
     ...: n_rows = 1000
     ...: n_columns = 1000
     ...: rows = np.random.randint(0,1000,(100000))
     ...: columns = np.random.randint(0,1000,(100000))

In [310]: %timeit add_at_app(rows, columns, n_rows, n_columns)
     ...: %timeit bincount_app(rows, columns, n_rows, n_columns)
     ...: %timeit mask_diff_app(rows, columns, n_rows, n_columns)
     ...: %timeit sparse_matrix_app(rows, columns, n_rows, n_columns)
100 loops, best of 3: 11.4 ms per loop
1000 loops, best of 3: 1.27 ms per loop
100 loops, best of 3: 7.44 ms per loop
10 loops, best of 3: 20.4 ms per loop
```

Case #3 : Sparse-ness in output

As stated earlier, for the sparse method to work better, we would need sparse-ness. Such a case would be like this -

```
In [314]: # Setup
     ...: n_rows = 5000
     ...: n_columns = 5000
     ...: rows = np.random.randint(0,5000,(1000))
     ...: columns = np.random.randint(0,5000,(1000))

In [315]: %timeit add_at_app(rows, columns, n_rows, n_columns)
     ...: %timeit bincount_app(rows, columns, n_rows, n_columns)
     ...: %timeit mask_diff_app(rows, columns, n_rows, n_columns)
     ...: %timeit sparse_matrix_app(rows, columns, n_rows, n_columns)
100 loops, best of 3: 11.7 ms per loop
100 loops, best of 3: 11.1 ms per loop
100 loops, best of 3: 11.1 ms per loop
1000 loops, best of 3: 269 µs per loop
```

If you need a dense array, we lose the memory efficiency and hence performance one as well -

```
In [317]: %timeit sparse_matrix_app(rows, columns, n_rows, n_columns).toarray()
100 loops, best of 3: 11.7 ms per loop
```