# Two-array counting in NumPy

Tags: python, arrays, numpy, time-complexity, counting

I have two (1-dimensional) NumPy arrays of integers, `a` and `b`. I want to produce a `counts` array which counts the occurrence of pairs of unique numbers between `a` and `b` (eg `(a[3], b[3])` is a pair, `(a[52], b[52])` is another), where the `counts` array is split into individual numbers from `a` and `b`. For example:

```
import numpy as np

Na = 8
Nb = 3
a = np.array([1, 1, 2, 0, 0, 3, 1, 2, 2, 0, 3, 3, 4, 5, 5, 6, 6, 4, 4, 5])
b = np.array([0, 0, 0, 2, 2, 0, 0, 0, 2, 2, 0, 1, 1, 1, 1, 0, 1, 1, 1, 1])

counts = np.zeros((Na, Nb), dtype=np.int64)
for j in range(len(a)):
    counts[a[j], b[j]] += 1

print(counts)
```

Producing:

```
array([[0, 0, 2],
       [2, 0, 0],
       [2, 0, 1],
       [2, 1, 0],
       [0, 2, 0],
       [0, 2, 0],
       [1, 1, 0],
       [0, 0, 0]])
```

However, I have arrays `a` and `b` with ~10<sup>7</sup> elements, and `Na` can be around 10<sup>7</sup> as well (with correspondingly large values in `a`, though `Nb` and `b`'s values are still less than 10), thus this algorithm is not optimal (around 40 seconds on my laptop, but I need to do this ~1000 times, so I'm hoping for about 5-10 seconds).

I was wondering if there is a more NumPy-vectorised solution, for example using [`np.unique`](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.unique.html). I don't expect the complexity to be better than the example above, but transferring the for-loop to C would be nice.

I've tried the other approach: iterate through each possibility in `a` and `b`:

```
for j in range(Na):
    for k in range(Nb):
        counts[j, k] += np.sum(a==j & b==k)
```

But this turns out to be significantly slower (multiple years), even with fancy vectorisation using [`np.meshgrid`](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.meshgrid.html) and [`np.expand_dims`](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.expand_dims.html), not to mention the RAM issues caused by `np.meshgrid`.

PS: I imaging a solution would be generalisable to N input arrays, with an N-dimensional `counts` array output.

Comment: Can you mention your expected o/p for the current a and b ?

Comment: This is definitely a duplicate. Thanks for pointing me in the right spot: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48139239/fill-matrix-of-occurences-from-column-row-arrays-of-indexes , which has the answer: `np.add.at(counts, (a, b), 1)`